# FreeRTOS stuck in vListInsert

Tags: freertos, cortex-m

I'm using FreeRTOS 10.0.1 and have a really hard problem, trying to solve it for days, getting my code to run on a CC1310 (Arm Cortex M3).
I use the TI SDK and read data from a I2C device, first time is successful, second gets stuck in the vListInsert, with the pxIterator->pxNext points to itself, so the for loop is infinite.

The driver is waiting for a SemaphoreP_pend(), if I set a breakpoint, I can see that the post gets called, but the kernel is just stuck.

I have set the SysTick and PendSV isr prio to 7 (lowest).

The i2c interrupt is prio 6.

configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY is set to 1.

There is no stack overflow as far as I can tell.

Please help, how do I debug this problem ?

Best regards
Jakob

Comment: More details are needed about your tasks & interrupts and the communication between them. Please show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the Issue, after getting help from @realtime-rik, I decided to check all my interrupt priorities again. They where all ok, but in the process I discovered two things.

1. The TI-SDK had structs with buffers in some of the drivers, which where rtos dependent, so their size should be set manually for each driver depending on the rtos usage.
2. I called the board init function in main before the scheduler was started, and inside board init, one of the drivers was using FreeRTOS queues. I have moved board init to my thread now.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a problem with interrupt priorities and the list getting corrupted. The interrupt priority is stored in the top 3 bits in your case (as there are 3 priority bits). So 7 is stored as 7 << 5 (11100000b) (you can pad the lower bits with 1 if you like so priority 7 == 255). This is handled by FreeRTOS.

What I suspect is happening is your I2C interrupt of priority 6, is not being << 5 so you have 00000110b which gives a priority of 0 (highest, as its the top 3 bits)

Comment: I can look again.

Comment: But I’m almost certain that SysTick and PendSV has value 0xE0 and I2C ISR has value 0xC0.

Comment: I have used FreeRTOS on many different Cortex-M platforms and a corrupted list is almost always due to interrupt priorities. I would manually check that all the priority registers have the correct value (also check that you have set the correct priority register for the I2C). Also check that you are only using FromISR functions in interrupts. Do you have any other interrupts?

Comment: Also be aware some functionswill expect you to set 6 and other 0xC0 (some do the shifting, so don't). If 0xC0 got <<5 then it would be 0.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue with FreeRTOS getting stuck in vListInsert() when I accidentally disabled interrupts and tried to disable interrupts again. Make sure you don't have a call to taskENTER_CRITICAL() followed by portDISABLE_INTERRUPTS().